# Python BeautifulSoup get ID

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I created a list and need to find the 'id's of the list. The list looks like:

```
x = [<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="19th_century">19th century</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="20th_century">20th century</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="21st_century">21st century</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Boundaries">Boundaries</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Topography">Topography</span></h3>]
```

I tried something like

```
x[0].contents
```

"find.all" and so on but really don't know how to get the id.

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illinois"
mybytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
mybytes = mybytes.read().decode("utf8") 
type(mybytes)

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(mybytes, features = 'lxml') 
type(parsed_html)

x = parsed_html.body.find_all("h3")
#x[0].contents('table', attrs={'id':'data_table'})

x[0:3]
```

Comment: That's not valid python. Post something we can use then perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are parsing html with BeautifulSoup, you can use `find_all` to get all the elements you want and then get the IDs:

```py
x = """<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="19th_century">19th century</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="20th_century">20th century</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="21st_century">21st century</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Boundaries">Boundaries</span></h3>,
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Topography">Topography</span></h3>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml")
for tag in soup.find_all("span") :
    print(tag.get('id'))
```

#### Output:

```
19th_century
20th_century
21st_century
Boundaries
Topography
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me